# VBA OnKey Run on Start

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have an OnKey sub that I use to iterate dates in a selected cell and when I close excel the OnKey designations return to default. Any idea how I can have excel remember the OnKey designations in a workbook so that when I open the work book it remembers the OnKey designations?

Currently I have to open the Modules and run them through break mode before the OnKey designation will work in the workbook.

heres the code in question

```
Sub CtrlUPKeystroke()
Application.OnKey "^{UP}", "IterationByDay"
End Sub

Sub IterationByDay()
Calculate
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = DateAdd("y", 1, Now)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just put the code in `Workbook_Open`.

Comment: Or better - leave it where it is, and *call it* from a `Workbook_Open` handler.

Comment: Thanks. the Handler in     ThisWorkbook is the way to go runs prefectly